# Making a simplistic video game

Tags: c, graphics

I'm thinking about creating a simplistic video game. I'm not talking about anything fancy, but about a game like this:

[image: Pole Position (1982)]

Since I want to learn, I would prefer not to use libraries but roll as much as I can on my own. I'd need to know how to render the car and the track, deal with collision with other cars, etc. I'm targeting Linux, Mac OS X and iOS. I fear that using a library like OpenGL makes things "too simple".

Are there any good resources out there that discuss this? Most of the tutorials / papers I have found are based around popular libraries & engines.

Comment: What language/platform? What features?

Comment: I'd have thought you'd probably get a better reception/audience for such a question over on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ but you might as well leave it here for a while as well and see how it goes.

Comment: Your question is exceptionally vague.

Comment: @Oded: Just racing around, maybe a few opponent cars. I thought the screenshot pretty much shows the complexity of what I'd like to do.

Comment: Pole position not fancy??? I disagree.

Comment: @ryyst - What **programming** language? What Operating System and Hardware are you targeting? A screen shot of pole position doesn't tell us any of that.

Comment: You can't program a game without a "library" like OpenGL/DirectX. That's like writing C++ without the Standard library.

Comment: @Oded: Added some more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're interested in learning from the level of [Simple DirectMedia Layer](http://www.libsdl.org/).

If so, this might be a good place to start: http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/moving-sprites-with-sdl/

Probably followed by: http://www.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL#Creating_a_Complete_2D_Engine

Also, for that particular rendering style, see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling#The_raster_method
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_7

**Edit:**
This information about the original Doom engine may be useful:
http://fabiensanglard.net/doomIphone/doomClassicRenderer.php

Also, Chocolate Doom is a port of the original Doom source into SDL, so you'll probably learn some useful patterns studying the source for it:
http://www.chocolate-doom.org

Answer (score 3):

> **"** *I fear that using a library like OpenGL makes things "too simple"* **"**

Don't worry, you still have plenty of work left.

In the REAL world, programmers use as many libraries as they can, that is the only way to produce a applications that focus on how things should work and not spend years on every little feature.

Start out programming above libraries, then, if you want to divide down into details, implement your own library and replace the one you used with it.

Dividing your application into self contained parts is a good practice, makes changing it without breaking everything possible.

Also, I would recommend you learn C++ first. Being able to model your problem domain with Object Oriented methodologies will help you break down the problems into solvable units.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already know C++. The thing is, I _want_ to work at a really low level. It's not the game I particularly care about. I'd like to apply all the things I know about linear algebra to a project. For example, see [this link](http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/mode7.htm). It explains how you can achieve Mode 7 using affine transforms etc.

Comment: So write a rendering engine and simple unit tests above it. You can use C++ to overload operators such as *= to make usage of the engine simpler (multiplying matrices/vectors). Start with read a little "Computer Graphics". Here is a link to good lecture slides: http://www.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Courses/559-f2004/cs559.html

Comment: Another form of even lower level is Assembly, but I would not recommend writing complex computer graphics in it.

Comment: Another tip, training or example code isn't always the best code to reference from. They are commonly written by inexperienced students or engineers and full of bad practices - from naming conventions to unmaintainable spaghetti code. Understand first, then design and only then write.

Answer (score 1):

It will be more or less impossible to develop a game without using any library. I guess you would have to go back to good old C64 days to do that. If you are interested in learning, I would look for a more low level library, which provides access to graphics, sound, ... But it should leave the logic to you.

I would propose to have a look at http://www.pygame.org/. It makes working with graphics, sprites, ... easy, is still relativly low level and Python is a great language to get started with.